# Points of intersection of two functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Through the following steps I found the x-coordinates of the intersection points of two functions: 
$(x)= -x^{2}+3x+1\:  and\: g(x)=3/x $
The numbers I found are x=(1, 2, 3) 
But on the graph, one of the points has a negative x value, could you guys point me to anything I have missed in my calculations.

$-x^{2}+3x+1=3/x
\\x(-x^{2}+3x+1)=3
\\x=3 
\\and
\\-x^{2}+3x+1=3
\\x^{2}-3x-1=-3 
\\x^{2}-3x-1+3=-3+3
\\x^{2}-3x+2=0
\\(x-1)(x-2)=0 
\\So 
\\x=1 \:and\: x=2
$

Comment: $x(-x^{2}+3x+1)=3\quad$ doesn't implies $x=3$ or $-x^{2}+3x+1=3$. Instead of that we have 
$$x(-x^{2}+3x+1)=3\iff -x^3+3x^2+x-3=0$$

Comment: your mistake is $-x^2+3x+1=3$ this is only true when $x=1$ you need to solve $f(x)=-x^3+3x^3+x-3=0$ knowing that $x=3$ is one solution. Divide $f(x)$ by $(x-3)$ to get a quadratic which you can solve to get the other 2 roots.

Answer (score 2):

$x(-x^{2}+3x+1)=3\quad$ doesn't imply $x=3$ or $-x^{2}+3x+1=3$. Instead of that we have 
$$x(-x^{2}+3x+1)=3\iff -x^3+3x^2+x-3=0\iff-(x+1)(x-1)(x-3)=0$$
Therefore the graphs of the functions mets at $x=-1$, $x=1$ and $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is a cubic, $  -(x+1)(x-1) (x-3) = 0,  $

with roots $ x = \pm 1, 3 $ at points of intersection.